# create mean per row for every second column

Tags: r

So what I am trying to do is to create a mean for each row, but only including every second column. An example df would be:

```
C1<-c(3,2,4,4,5)
C2<-c(3,7,3,4,5)
C3<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
C4<-c(5,4,3,6,3)
C5<-c(5,6,3,6,2)
C6<-c(5,5,3,6,4)
C7<-c(5,6,3,6,1)
C8<-c(5,7,3,6,2)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"),C1=C1,C2=C2,C3=C3, C4=C4, C5=C5, C6=C6, C7=C7, C8=C8)

 DF
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
1  A  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5
2  B  2  7  4  4  6  5  6  7
3  C  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
4  D  4  4  6  6  6  6  6  6
5  E  5  5  3  3  2  4  1  2
```

So now I would like to calculate the mean of C2, C4, C6 and C8 and add this as a new column in the df. What I tried is this:

```
DF$mean <- rowMeans(DF[seq(2, nrow(dat_all_b), 2),])
```

This is the error produced: "Fehler in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, frequency_mean, value = c(`350` = NA,  :
replacement has 14 rows, data has 30"
Fehler = error

My actual df has way more columns and i want to calculate the mean across every second column.
Expected output:

```
 DF
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 mean_1
1  A  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5   4,5
2  B  2  7  4  4  6  5  6  7   5,75
3  C  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3    3
4  D  4  4  6  6  6  6  6  6    5,5
5  E  5  5  3  3  2  4  1  2   3,5
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I updated it with more columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowMeans` for every 2nd column as :

```
DF$mean_1 <- rowMeans(DF[seq(3, ncol(DF), 2)], na.rm = TRUE)
DF

#  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 mean_1
#1  A  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5   4.50
#2  B  2  7  4  4  6  5  6  7   5.75
#3  C  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3.00
#4  D  4  4  6  6  6  6  6  6   5.50
#5  E  5  5  3  3  2  4  1  2   3.50
```

This gives mean of `C2`, `C4`, `C6` and `C8`. I am not sure if you need another column called `mean_2` which would be mean of `C1`, `C3`, `C5` and `C7` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
rowwise() %>%
mutate(mean = mean(c(C1, C2), na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. So my actual data frame has way more columns, so working with the column names seems unefficient. I edited my question accordingly. Do you have any idea, how to command that every second column should be included?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you mean of every even numbered column if we leave `ID` column.

```
DF$mean_1 <- rowMeans(DF[(seq_along(DF)[(seq_along(DF) %% 2 == 1)])][-1])

  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 mean_1
1  A  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5   4.50
2  B  2  7  4  4  6  5  6  7   5.75
3  C  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3.00
4  D  4  4  6  6  6  6  6  6   5.50
5  E  5  5  3  3  2  4  1  2   3.50
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into the apply family.
In this case, by using apply and set the margin to 1 (by row -- while setting it to 2 will give you the mean by column) will solve the issue.

```
DF$mean <- apply(DF[,2:ncol(DF)], 1, mean)
```

Please note, this is more flexible as you can also quickly adapt to a number of other cases. as an example, to get the maximum value by row you can apply the max function by row to your dataframe:

```
DF$max <- apply(DF[,2:ncol(DF)], 1, max)
```